# Lipschitz Smoothness implying strong convexity

Tags: functions, vector-analysis

I recently stumbled upon [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673898/lipschitz-smoothness-strong-convexity-and-the-hessian?newreg=eb3bafdeb65b4aaf92f58bae6208577f).

After playing around with the definition a bit I am just not able to see why L-Lipschitz-Smoothness implies the inequality mentioned in 1:

$$ f(x + y) \leq f(x) + y^\top \nabla f(x) + \frac{L}{2} \| y \|^2 $$

I would love some pointers if anyone has any.

Answer (score 0):

This **exact** proof is contained in Bertsekas' Nonlinear Programming 2nd Edition Proposition A. 24 called the "Descent Lemma".