# Show that Lipschitz $\|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\| \leq L\|x - y\|$ is implied by $f(y) \leq f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T(y-x) + \dfrac{L}{2}\|y-x\|^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, proof-writing, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Pg 12 - 14 http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/gradient.pdf

**Def**: A $C^1$ *convex* function $f$ is Lipschitz smooth if $\exists L > 0$ s.t. $\forall x, y\in \mathbb{R}^n$
    \begin{equation}
  \|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\| \leq L\|x - y\|
 \end{equation}

> **Claim:** A $C^1$ convex function $f$ that satisfies $$f(y) \leq f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T(y-x) + \dfrac{L}{2}\|y-x\|^2$$ is Lipschitz Smooth

(Note: 1. the reverse implication is referred to as the "quadratic upper bound property" 2. One poster suggested to use fenchel duality to show this [Lipschitz Smoothness, Strong Convexity and the Hessian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673898/lipschitz-smoothness-strong-convexity-and-the-hessian?noredirect=1&lq=1))

**Proof attempt:**

It seems that the direct approach is through re-arrange and combine, which gives: 
$$0 \leq (\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y))^T(y-x) +  L\|y-x\|^2$$
$$(\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x))^T(y-x) \leq    L\|y-x\|^2$$

Using CS-inequality on the above $(\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x))^T(y-x) \leq    L\|y-x\|^2$ gives:

$$(\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x))^T(y-x) \leq    \|\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x)\|\|y-x\|$$
Now I have:

1. $$(\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x))^T(y-x) \leq    L\|y-x\|^2$$
2. $$(\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x))^T(y-x) \leq    \|\nabla f(y)-\nabla
       f(x)\|\|y-x\|$$

How do I conclude $\|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\| \leq L\|x - y\|$?

---

Comment: It seem's like first three terms of taylor series.

Comment: See what. The last expression you got, is exactly Cauchy-Swartz inequlaity(if we require positivness, and Lipshitz continuity.) So maybe it should be if and only if ?.

Comment: I have a question: Could you explain the first line of the proof attempt ? What did you rearrange and combine ? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Co-coercivity of the gradient ([Lecture 1, slides 15-16](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/gradient.pdf) in Vandenberghe's 236c notes) tells us that
$$
\frac{1}{L} \| \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x) \|^2 \leq 
(\nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x))^T (y - x)
$$
for all $x,y$.
Now combine this with your equation 1) to conclude that
$$ 
\| \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x) \| \leq L \| y - x \|
$$
for all $x,y$.