# how to prove a property of smooth function

Tags: inequality, convex-optimization

Considering a **convex** function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, if it is a $\beta$-smooth function, namely
$$\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n, \quad f(y) \leq f(x) + \nabla f(x)^\mathrm{T}(y-x)+\frac{\beta}{2}\lVert y-x \rVert^2 $$

then we have 
$$\lVert \nabla f(x)\rVert^2 \leq \beta f(x) $$

This conclusion comes from a [lecture note](http://papail.io/teaching/901/lecture04_scribe.pdf) from Dimitris Papailiopoulos's course ECE 901 but without proof.

I just wanna figure out how to prove this conclusion? Thx.

Comment: Seems that this property does not hold. A counterexample due to @Willie is any linear function $f(x)=Lx$ is convex and $\beta$-smooth for any $\beta \geq 0$. But $\| \nabla f(0)\|^2 = \|L\|^2 \not\leq \beta f(0) = 0$ whenever $L \neq 0$.

Comment: On further study I do think you're right about the second inequality. The lecture notes themselves say that linear & affine functions are $0$-smooth. But $\|\nabla f(x)\|^2$ is a constant in those cases.

Comment: Now I know the inequality only holds for positive-valued smooth functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copied incorrectly the definition of $\beta$-smooth. In the lecture notes you linked to, $\beta$-smooth is defined by 
$$ \| \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) \| \leq \beta \| x - y\|. $$
(What you copied down is almost the definition of $\beta$-strong convex; you have the wrong inequality.)

That said, the claim you are asking about is false (at least without additional assumptions). Any linear function $f(x) = Lx$ is convex and $\beta$-smooth for any $\beta \geq 0$. But $\| \nabla f(0)\|^2 = \|L\|^2 \not\leq \beta f(0) = 0$ whenever $L \neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your counterexample, I think you are right, this claim should be false. However, the definition above seems equivalent to your definition, which means $\quad f(y) \leq f(x) + \nabla f(x)^\mathrm{T}(y-x)+\frac{\beta}{2}\lVert y-x \rVert^2$ is equivalent to $\| \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) \| \leq \beta \| x - y\|.$ from Hazan's book [Hazan - Introduction to Online Convex Optimization](http://ocobook.cs.princeton.edu/OCObook.pdf) in Page 22. But anyone who knows how to prove it?

Comment: I found the proof of the equivalence https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020979/show-that-lipschitz-nabla-fx-nabla-fy-leq-l-x-y-is-implied-b?rq=1