# Best constant for Lipschitz continuous gradient function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, lipschitz-functions

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^{d} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function with Lipschitz continuous gradient, that is there exists $L \geq 0$ such that:
\begin{equation}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\left\lVert \nabla f (x) - \nabla f (y) \right\rVert \leq L \left\lVert x - y \right\rVert , \forall x , y \in \mathbb{R}^{d} .
\end{equation}
Find the smallest $\sigma \geq 0$ such that
\begin{equation}
\label{2}\tag{2}
f(x) \geq f(y) + \left\langle x - y , \nabla f(y) \right\rangle - \dfrac{\sigma}{2} \left\lVert x - y \right\rVert ^{2} , \forall x , y \in \mathbb{R}^{d} .
\end{equation}

(If $f$ is convex then $\sigma = 0$. However, we do not have this assumption here)

**My attempt:**
Since $f$ is $L-$Lipschitz continuous gradient, then we have (see, for example [Show that Lipschitz $\|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\| \leq L\|x - y\|$ is implied by $f(y) \leq f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T(y-x) + \dfrac{L}{2}\|y-x\|^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020979/show-that-lipschitz-nabla-fx-nabla-fy-leq-l-x-y-is-implied-b)):
\begin{equation}
f (y) \leq f (x) + \left\langle y - x , \nabla f(x) \right\rangle + \dfrac{L}{2} \left\lVert y - x \right\rVert ^{2}
\end{equation}
which implies:
\begin{align*}
f \left( x \right) & \geq f \left( y \right) + \left\langle x - y , \nabla f \left( x \right) \right\rangle - \dfrac{L}{2} \left\lVert x - y \right\rVert ^{2} \\
& = f \left( y \right) + \left\langle x - y , \nabla f \left( y \right) \right\rangle + \left\langle x - y , \nabla f \left( x \right) - \nabla f \left( y \right) \right\rangle - \dfrac{L}{2} \left\lVert x - y \right\rVert ^{2} \\
& \geq f \left( y \right) + \left\langle x - y , \nabla f \left( y \right) \right\rangle - \left\lVert x - y \right\rVert \left\lVert \nabla f \left( x \right) - \nabla f \left( y \right) \right\rVert - \dfrac{L}{2} \left\lVert x - y \right\rVert ^{2} \\
& \geq f \left( y \right) + \left\langle x - y , \nabla f \left( y \right) \right\rangle - \dfrac{3L}{2} \left\lVert x - y \right\rVert ^{2}
\end{align*}
where the second inequality I used the Cauchy - Schwarz inequality and the last one is by the Lipschitz continuity. So my constant is $\sigma = 3L$.

**However**, the best posible constant (again, without convexity assumption) should be $\sigma = L$. So where did I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $x(t) := t x + (1-t)y$.
We have that
$$
\begin{split}
f(x) - f(y) & = \int_0^1 \langle\nabla f(x(t)), x-y\rangle\, dt
\\ & = \int_0^1 \langle\nabla f(x(t)) - \nabla f(y), x-y\rangle\, dt
+ \langle\nabla f(y), x-y\rangle.
\end{split}
$$
On the other hand
$$
\begin{split}
& \left|\int_0^1 \langle\nabla f(x(t)) - \nabla f(y), x-y\rangle\, dt\right|
\leq \int_0^1 \| \nabla f(x(t)) - \nabla f(y)\| \, \|x-y\|\, dt
\\ & \leq L \int_0^1 \|x(t) - y\|\, \|x-y\|\, dt
= L \|x-y\|^2 \int_0^1 t\, dt = \frac{L}{2}\|x-y\|^2,
\end{split}
$$
so that
$$
f(x) - f(y) \geq \langle\nabla f(y), x-y\rangle
- \frac{L}{2}\|x-y\|^2\,.
$$

Comment: thank you. but does it means that the best constant is $L$ only when the function is smooth? if the property is not Lipschitz continuous gradient but Lipschitz continuous subdifferential, that is, there exists $L \geq 0$ such that
$$ \left\lVert \hat{\nabla} f (x) - \hat{\nabla} f (y) \right\rVert \leq L \left\lVert x - y \right\rVert , \forall x , y \in \mathbb{R}^{d} , \hat{\nabla} f (x) \in \partial f(x) \hat{\nabla} f (y) \in \partial f(y) $$
then your approach can not applied anymore?

Comment: What do you mean by Lipschitz continuous subdifferential? Anyway, condition (2) is shared by any semi-concave function (and, in that case, $\sigma$ is the so-called semiconcavity constant of the function).

Comment: roughly speaking Lipschitz continuous subdifferential is an extend definition of Lipschitz continuous gradient for nonsmooth function

Comment: uhm. I think that, using any definition of subdifferential, the assumption of Lipschitz continuity implies that the subdifferential is single-valued and the function is of class $C^1$.

Comment: thank you. I will think more about it. just a curious question :)