# A variant of Lipschitz inequality

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lipschitz-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a $L$-Lipschitz function: $\|f(x)-f(y)\| \le L \|x-y\|$, $L >0$.

How to prove $\|f(x)-f(y)\|^2 \le L \left( f(x)-f(y)\right)^T (x-y)$?

---

Update:
Sorry, I forget to specify an important condition: in fact, $f$
is the gradient of a convex function.

Comment: What norm are you working with? And what have you tried thus far?

Comment: I doubt that such an estimate exists generally. Try $f(x) = -x$ for example.

Comment: It is euclidean norm. I can only prove $∥f(x)−f(y)∥^2≤L ∥f(x)−f(y)∥ ∥x−y∥$. I don't know how to pass ∥f(x)−f(y)∥ ∥x−y∥ to (f(x)−f(y))^T(x−y). @Keen-ameteur

Comment: Ah That's true... @MartinR Maybe my professor used something else to get this inequality...

Comment: Another counterexample: A rotation by 90 degrees in $\Bbb R^2$: the right-hand side is zero for all $x, y$.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to specify an important condition: in fact, $f$ is the gradient of a convex function. @MartinR

Comment: This may be what you are looking for: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2021718/42969.