# Strong-convexity parameter dimension dependency for $1/2$-Tsallis-entropy with respect to $\|\cdot\|_1$ on the unit simplex.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convex-optimization, upper-lower-bounds, convexity-inequality

Let $K \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $f:(0,1)^K \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function $x \mapsto - 2 \sum_{k=1}^K \sqrt{x_k}$ (that, apart from constants, it is the $1/2$-Tsallis entropy). I'm trying to figure out what is the biggest $\mu>0$ such that $f$ is $\mu$-strongly convex with respect to $\|\cdot\|_1$ (where $\|x\|_1 = \sum_{k=1}^K |x_k|$) on the unit simplex $D := \{ x\in (0,1) ^K \mid \sum_{k=1}^K x_k = 1\}$. Specifically, I'm trying to figure out what is the correct dependence on $\mu := \mu(K)$ w.r.t. to the dimensional parameter $K$ in the relation
\begin{equation}
   \forall x,y \in D, \qquad f(y)\ge f(x)+\mathbb{d}f(x)(y-x)+\frac{\mu}{2} \|y-x\|_1^2.
\end{equation}

So far, what I did was noticing that $\mathbb{d}^2f \succeq \frac{1}{2}I$ on $(0,1)^K$ (i.e., $\mathbb{d}^2f(x)-\frac{1}{2} I$ is positive semidefinite for each $x \in (0,1)^K$, a fact that it is easily seen computing the Hessian of $f$) and that $\sqrt{K}\|\cdot\|_2 \ge \|\cdot\|_1$ (where $\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^K x_k^2}$), which [implies (see question 3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/708575/233540) that
\begin{equation}
   \forall x,y \in (0,1)^K, \qquad f(y)\ge f(x)+\mathbb{d}f(x)(y-x)+\frac{1/2}{2} \|y-x\|_2^2 \ge f(x)+\mathbb{d}f(x)(y-x)+\frac{1/(2K)}{2} \|y-x\|_1^2 .
\end{equation}
so, in particular, we can select $\mu = \frac{1}{2K}$.

However, there were several (probably non-sharp) inequalities in between (and the result holds on an even bigger set), so I strongly suspect that the dependence on the dimensional parameter $K$ is sloppy.

Does anyone else have any better ideas?